# BizTalk extract part of XML message to another

Tags: xml, biztalk

I have an XML file with:

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <doc:Request>
        ... some XML text as flat text or like XML ...
      </doc:Request>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to save text between `<doc:Request>` `</doc:Request>` to new a message and save it as an XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an Orchestration, use the `xpath()` in a Message Assignment shape:

```
msgExtracted = xpath(msgSoap, "/*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body']/*[local-name()='Request']");
```

In a custom pipeline component, load the `pInMsg.BodyPart.GetOriginalDataStream()` into an XmlReader, and then `ReadToFollowing("Request", "namespace_for_doc_here");` node and then use `reader.ReadSubtree()` to get it and return it as the message.

Finally, since there's a good possibility you're using a WCF based adapter anyway, you may be able to specify the `Body XPath` of the message in the adapter settings - or just tell the adapter to include the SOAP body and not the envelope.

Answer (score 2):

Create a distinguished field in the incoming message schema (Make sure you are taking a copy of the schema for best practices) which points to **doc:Request** (I'm assuming that the **doc** namespace is registered in the message). Then create a Message Assignment Shape and simply instantiate a new message of the required type (you will need a new schema which describes **doc:Request** of course)

newMessageType.body = incomingMessage.Request;

You could do it by xpath if you really must but please know that for each time you execute an xpath query, the entire message is loading into memory. This can result in a massive overhead if your messages are large or you have a large number of xpath queries. In addition, your xpath can be difficult to read if your message is complex. Where a distinguished field will always be easy to read and if you update your schema, you don't need to alter the orchestration. I'd strongly recommend against using xpath!

**Note**
If the sole purpose of your task here is to get that bit out of the message and save it as an XML file as you state here, you don't even need an orchestration. You can add a map to the receive port which transforms to the new message type and have a send port subscribe to the output **doc:Request** message which simple saves via a file adapter.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but using a Distinguished field this way will also load the entire message into memory.  Internally, a distinguished field is just a way of storing an XPath in the schema instead of the Orchestration.

Comment: I think you're right in that it uses xpath but I do believe that distinguished fields are cached during pipeline execution, where the message is being parsed and loaded into memory anyway. Where xpath loads the message again and again on demand. So even using just one xpath query will result in slower performance.

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying.  Yes, using a distinguished field would avoid loading a DOM for that message.

Answer (score 1):

The xpath and distinguished field will work. But isn't the easy way is define the xml content struct with soapenv namespace as an envelop schema, then let the xmldisassmbler do the rest of thing?

Comment: In fact it's one adapter for several clients with standart form. But for each i need to extract not the same part...